# Resque clean out failed jobs are successful retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

Is it currently possible to clean out failed jobs once they have been successful after a forced retry? Currently the failed queue stays in tact with the same number as failures as there was prior to the retry. Is there a tool or something builtin Resque that handles managing this better than the default behavior?

Comment: There must be a plugin for this

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but a quick google found resque cleaner:

https://github.com/ono/resque-cleaner

We use resque and resque-status but manually clear the queue so we can see what's broken etc.